# how to increase limit for facebook insights api cursor

Tags: python, facebook, cursor, facebook-insights

I am using async method to generate the insights report. In order to get data from it, I am iterating over the results where it gives me 25 values at a time. How can I increase this limit?

More details:

Logs:

```
2017-03-30 09:27:41.926362  DEBUG   171:0   facebook.py:get_ads_insight     insights type: <class 'facebookads.api.Cursor'>
2017-03-30 09:27:41.926979  DEBUG   176:0   facebook.py:get_ads_insight     insights present: 25
```

Insights API facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/async/v2.8

Sample code:

```
from facebookads.adobjects.campaign import Campaign
from facebookads.adobjects.adsinsights import AdsInsights
from facebookads.adobjects.adreportrun import AdReportRun
import time

campaign = Campaign(<CAMPAIGN_ID>)
params = {
    'level': AdsInsights.Level.campaign,
}
async_job = campaign.get_insights(params=params, async=True)

async_job.remote_read()

while async_job[AdReportRun.Field.async_percent_completion] < 100:
    time.sleep(1)
    async_job.remote_read()

time.sleep(1)

print(async_job.get_result())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameters to `get_result()`, for example:

`async_job.get_result(params={'limit': '100',})`

Answer (score 0):

Add another entry for `limit` into your `params`-dict (with declaring `limit = 0` or so before):

```
params = {
    'limit': limit if limit > 0 else None,
}
```